# Pandas force matrix multiplication

Tags: python, pandas, matrix-multiplication, dot-product, dataframe

I would like to force matrix multiplication "orientation" using Python Pandas, both between DataFrames against DataFrames, Dataframes against Series and Series against Series.

As an example, I tried the following code:

```
t = pandas.Series([1, 2])
print(t.T.dot(t))
```

Which outputs: 5

But I expect this:

```
[1 2
 2 4]
```

Pandas is great, but this inability to do matrix multiplications the way I want is what is the most frustrating, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I know Pandas tries to implicitly use index to find the right way to compute the matrix product, but it seems this behavior can't be switched off!

Comment: A series is a 1-dimensional object; its transpose is (vacuously
defined to be) itself.  Even in pure numpy, `a = np.array([1,2]);
a.dot(a.T)` will give `5`. Why not simply write a function -- `silly_dot` -- using the same `a[:,None]` tricks you'd use in `numpy` which gives the behaviour you want?

Comment: I don't know about numpy tricks, but even if it would work for Series, it would not for DataFrames. I would just like Pandas to work matrix multiplications like in Octave when I need to: a simple t'*t would solve the problem in Octave. Why not in Pandas?

Comment: you should check out this page: http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935, there are myriad reasons why ``*`` means element-wise multiplication and not dot-product, but as DSM points out, you can create a function to emulation what you are looking for

Comment: I never said that it was silly that * does element-wise multiplication (you can reread my comment), but it's silly that there's no way in pandas to dot multiply without indexes alignment. Without matrix multiplications, vectorization is just not possible (and creating my own emulation function would only make things worse).

Comment: It also would be nice to have pandas support this so that you don't have to down-convert to numpy than up-convert back to pandas structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone coming to this now may want to consider: [pandas.Series.to_frame()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html). It's kind of clunky.

Here's the original question's example:

```
import pandas as pd

t = pd.Series([1, 2])

t.to_frame() @ t.to_frame().T
# or equivalently:
t.to_frame().dot(t.to_frame().T)
```

Which yields:

```
In [3]: t.to_frame().dot(t.to_frame().T)                                        
Out[3]: 
   0  1
0  1  2
1  2  4
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems indeed to be the correct modern way to do a matrix multiplication. I accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
In [1]: import pandas

In [2]: t = pandas.Series([1, 2])

In [3]: np.outer(t, t)
Out[3]:
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 4]])
```

Comment: Perfect, it works perfectly well! Pandas should add .outer() to Series and DataFrames (even if it means losing the indexes in the process, this kind of operation is very often needed!).

Comment: Wait: it indeed works for the example I've shown, but it doesn't exactly solve the whole question: whatever the orientation of t (can be t or transpose t), it always outputs the same result! I'd like to be able to force the orientation I want, not just have the outer dot product.

Comment: why don't you use dot vs outer instead of doing transpose? If you really need t to be treated as a 2-d matrix, you should be doing what @DSM suggested and do t = t[:, None]

Comment: Because I don't always want to do the dot or outer product, sometimes the result I expect is a vector (dot always output a scalar and outer always a matrix).

Answer (score 0):

Solution found by y-p:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3344#issuecomment-16533461

```
from pandas.util.testing import makeCustomDataframe as mkdf
a=mkdf(3,5,data_gen_f=lambda r,c: randint(1,100))
b=mkdf(5,3,data_gen_f=lambda r,c: randint(1,100))
c=DataFrame(a.values.dot(b.values),index=a.index,columns=b.columns)
print a
print b
print c
assert  (a.iloc[0,:].values*b.iloc[:,0].values.T).sum() == c.iloc[0,0]

C0       C_l0_g0  C_l0_g1  C_l0_g2  C_l0_g3  C_l0_g4
R0                                                  
R_l0_g0       39       87       88        2       65
R_l0_g1       59       14       76       10       65
R_l0_g2       93       69        4       29       58
C0       C_l0_g0  C_l0_g1  C_l0_g2
R0                                
R_l0_g0       76       88       11
R_l0_g1       66       73       47
R_l0_g2       78       69       15
R_l0_g3       47        3       40
R_l0_g4       54       31       31
C0       C_l0_g0  C_l0_g1  C_l0_g2
R0                                
R_l0_g0    19174    17876     7933
R_l0_g1    15316    13503     4862
R_l0_g2    16429    15382     7284
```

The assert here is useless, it just does a check that it's indeed a correct matrix multiplication.

The key here seems to be line 4:

```
c=DataFrame(a.values.dot(b.values),index=a.index,columns=b.columns)
```

What this does is that it computes the dot product of a and b, but force that the resulting DataFrame c has a's indexes and b's columns, indeed converting the dot product into a matrix multiplication, and in pandas's style since you keep the indexes and columns (you lose the columns of a and indexes of b, but this is semantically correct since in a matrix multiplication you are summing over those rows, so it would be meaningless to keep them).

This is a bit awkward but seems simple enough if it is consistent with the rest of the API (I still have to test what will be the result with Series x Dataframe and Series x Series, I will post here my findings).